# Proof that isomorphisms are unique in any category

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

So, I can’t prove that inverses are unique in integers, so I tried to demonstrate that inverses are unique more in general so that I won’t have to prove that all the inverses are unique category by category.

This is my demonstration:

I have an arrow $f:A \rightarrow B$, then I have another arrow $g: B \rightarrow A$ such that

$g\circ f = I_{A}$ and $f\circ g = I_{B}$

where $I_X$ is the identity arrow of $X$.

So say there is another inverse $h:B \rightarrow A$ such that $h\circ f = I_{A}$ and $f\circ h = I_{B}$, then I should be able to do the following calculations

$g\circ f=h\circ f$

$g\circ f\circ g=h\circ f \circ g$

$g\circ I_B=h\circ I_B$

$g=h$

Seemed a little bit too simple to me. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: Yes, it's that simple. Why do you think it should be complicated?

Comment: Because it's my first shot at math after 3 years out of uni as a programmer, in particular I wasn't sure I could just say, let's apply everything to g

Comment: Okay. Well a lot of math is much simpler than it first appears. Since you have a background in programming, you may find that learning and using a proof assistant to be valuable. This will allow you to know with confidence that you've made a valid proof or not. The experience is like a type checker. (In fact a lot of proof checkers *are* just type checkers.) You may find Benjamin Pierce's [Software Foundations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html) useful as a way of gaining familiarity with those tools which are admittedly non-trivial to learn.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of those